# Why is += valid temporaries in standard library?

Tags: c++, temporary

When I attempt to compile the following on [ideone](http://ideone.com/BaQoe):

```
class X
{
  public:
   friend X& operator+=(X& x, const X& y);
};

X& operator+=(X& x, const X& y) { return x; }

int main()
{
  X() += X();
}
```

As expected, this throws a compile error, because you can't pass a temporary to a non const reference.

However, the following compiles successfully on [ideone](http://ideone.com/PECyy):

```
std::string() += std::string();
```

Shouldn't this error like my example above?

**Edit:**

If std::string() defines `+=` as a member operation, why does it do this when such usage allows the left hand side to be a temporary? Why not define it as I have above and avoid the reference to temporary issues?

Comment: for the record, both compile in VC++ 10.0 with warning `warning C4239: nonstandard extension used : 'argument' : conversion from 'X' to 'X &'`

Comment: @DougT.: VS allows binding temps to non-const refs as an extension, so it's not a useful toolchain to test this on

Comment: -1 for radically changing the question after it was answered. Not cool. If you have follow-ups - ask a separate question, don't hijack your own question to ask something else entirely after the original has been answered.

Comment: Sorry littleadv. I've tagged the recent edit regarding member functions, and the original question was simply a mistake.

Comment: @Clinton: generally speaking, because they modify the original, compound operators (ie of the form `@=`) should be defined as member functions while binary operators (which usually do not change the original) should be defined as free functions. This is of course just a guideline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C++ rule is that you can't bind a temporary to a non-const reference. However, you can call non-const member functions on temporaries: if you define the `operator +=()` as a member, you can call it on your object. This is one of the tricks how to get a reference out of temporary, e.g. when using a temporary `std::istringstream` to read a non-basic type (basic types are read by members):

```
std::string word;
if (std::istringstream("hello world") >> std::ws >> word) { ... }
```

(yes, this *is* a silly example).

Answer (score 3):

Because it **is** `const`.

[string::operator+=](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator+=/)

changing to `X& operator+=(const X& y)` will make your code compile fine just as well.

**edit**

You changed the question after I've answered it already and changed the definition of your `X::operator+=` to be a `friend` function instead of a member function. That would indeed **not** work. Note that `std::string::operator+=` is not a `friend`, its a member function of `std::string`.

Comment: Oops, now I've modified the question though. Why don't doesn't the standard library define operator+= like I have above?

Comment: well, probably to allow "x+= string("y");" to work, for example. I see no reason why it should not allow that. If you only need to convert some type into std::string to add to another string, why not do it in this way?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "allow `x+= string("y");` to work. The example I give allows `x+= string("y");`, but disallows `string("x") += string("y")`.

Comment: No, the LHS is _not_ `const`. That would obviously not work. The op is a member function though, which is why it works.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit See my edit. My answer was to the original question, not the re-edited one.

Comment: @littleadv: It _was_ in English. From your edit, it looks like you figured it out. But linking to `std::string::operator+=` and saying "it _is_ `const`" was still silly, because the only `const` thing there is the RHS argument, which nobody has been talking about

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit its not silly if you read the original question. After I answered it, the guy decided to rewrite the question to ask something else, then my answer does indeed look out of context.

Comment: @littleadv: I did read the original question, in the edit history. That's why I said "still".

Answer (score 3):

```
string& operator+= ( const string& str );
```

feel the difference

Answer (score 0):

`operator+=` is usually overloaded as a member function, and member functions (`const` or otherwise) *can* be called on temporary *rvalues*.

If you change your overload to a member, `X& operator+=(const X&)`, then your example should also compile.